# html pattern attribute does not appear in red in NotePad++

Tags: html, design-patterns, attributes

I just want to understand why it doesn't, since all of the other attributes in my code are "red". (although the "pattern" attribute *does* work when launched)

[image]

```
Password:
<input type="password" name="password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Enter a password that is minimum 8 characters, 1 lowercase characher and 1 uppercase character."><br />
```

Comment: Which version of Np++ are you using?

Comment: Spirit, NP++v5.6.8

Comment: I would suggest updating it. You are using an older version.

Comment: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-7.5.4-released.html

Comment: Thank you so much, it should work. Any way I can upvote this?

Comment: You can upvote the comment.